# Не переведена подсказка в блоке ссылок под комментариями

Tags: дефект, локализация, комментарии, нет-в-transifex

У меня случайно задержался курсор мыши неподалёку от ссылки «Показать ещё 1 комментарий», и я увидел такую всплывашку:

> Expand to show all comments on this post, or add one of your own

Изначально её на странице нет — эксперимент показал, что она появляется только после того, как вебсокет пришлёт уведомление о наличии нового комментария.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Добавил переводы для первой части:

- [Expand to show all comments on this post](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15918)

Но, возможно, оно вообще не отсюда.

Второй части [`, or add one of your own`](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=add%20one%20of%20your%20own) в traducir не видно. Завёл багу на MSE [No string to translate "Expand to show all comments on this post"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393601/339911).

Текущая сборка 2023.10.4.43662.